# Passing in a value to a usercontrol through a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, foreach

in my asp.net mark up I have a foreach loop that iterates through a simple list. In this foreach loop I am adding a new user control and attempting to pass in the value from the loop. However, this value just wont budge and get inside that damn  control! Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<%foreach (userInfo i in this.items)
    { %>  
        <uc1:ItemControl ID="ItemControl" runat="server" UserID='<%#Eval("userID") %>'/>
<%} %>
```

userID is a public property in the control, when it goes to set, the value is just literally : <%#Eval("userID") %>. I've tried #Bind and =Value but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the perfect use case for a [repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx):

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="myRepeater">
   <uc1:ItemControl ID="ItemControl" runat="server" />
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can databind your list (`this.items`) to the repeater and in the code behind, in the `DataBind` event set the `UserID` property of the `ItemControl` control.

The reason your approach will not work is that IDs have to be unique in a page.

Answer (score 3):

Try use a Repeater control for your purpose